# How to fix Google Maps API RefererDeniedMapError

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am working on a web app that includes a map using the Google Maps Javascript API.  It works on our development server, but whenever trying to access it on stage or production using our company domain, I get an RefererDeniedMapError.

The docs at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#referer-denied-map-error clearly state that this error means Google has blocked our domain for violating ToS.  An appeal was submitted but Google claims the domain is not blocked and to see further help here.  I've already turned off all API restrictions and removed all referrer restrictions as well, but are still getting the same problems.

I can access the app by going directly to the web app server, but anytime I go through our company's domain name, the error returns, which leads me to believe that we are in fact blocked.

Has anyone experienced an issue like this or know of a workaround for this? I've looked through the related posts on the topic but have not found anything useful info to help resolve the problem.

Edit:

The website is using sensors to track packages in the mail for our customers and alerts them if the sensor gets too much light, is dropped, etc.  There are no restriction methods at all. I've added a couple screenshots showing the maps working on development but not during testing.

[Map working in development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Twg5R.png)

[Map not working on test server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/120ZU.png)

Comment: Can you share your use case for this? providing screenshots of the error will help and please share the restriction method that you are using and how you implement it.

Comment: @ShawnDomingo I have updated the original post to address your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

At first look, it just seems to be a normal restriction error, however, since you've said that there are currently no restrictions applied in your API key and is working properly in server-side but not in production, this seems to be an issue with your API key, can you try to generate a new API key and use it in your website? If the issue still persist, then this will require a technical support from Google Maps Platform as this may be an issue in the GCP Console. You may file a support case via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support in order to open personalized communication channel.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions - I'll try a new API Key and, if that doesn't work, file a support case.